# how to make flurry start gathering data at a certain date

Tags: ios, objective-c, flurry, flurry-analytics

Initially I had a single app registered with Flurry.. we used this app pre-launch for testing etc.. and flurry captured all the data from my testers etc. We have recently launched the app and basically made flurry only capture the data from live users (ie so that it doesn't get polluted by our testers actions).. is there a way to instruct flurry to erase or hide all the data it captured prelaunch and just show us the post launch data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of way of doing this is to select which version u're interested in looking at

[image]

the problem with this approach is that it only gives you stats for a *single* version..

another approach is to simply delete the versions that contains the polluted data.. this way you can go over the results of all the versions that have accurate data

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Flurry recommends that you create two or more projects for each app. You can use one project for development and testing and another for the published version of your app. Just don't forget to swap the api key when you publish the app.

This also has the benefit of splitting your versions up so you do not approach the limit of 1000 versions per project.

Alternatively you can use the timeframe filter to remove data that precedes the publication date of your app.